# What extra RPCs does web3 transact do?

Tags: web3.py

I am using the 'transact' function on the web3 generated contract functions, and I noticed it does a call to estimate gas before sending the transaction.  What other calls does it do?  Does it do calls for gasLimit and Nonce as well?

Comment: Which implementation? Doesn't sound like web3.js, perhaps you mean web3.py?

Comment: Yea, I am using web3.py

Comment: So why on earth is your question tagged under web3.js and web3j???